# Git merge upstream branch

Tags: git, github

I have a git system with upstream/origin/local .

upstream has branch b1 and b2
origin has branch b1
local has b1.

I want to put changes of b2 (which is b1 + some new commits) to origin b1.

I tried the command :

```
git fetch upstream b2
git checkout origin/b1
git merge upstream b2 (which shows a Fast-forward)
git push origin b1 (Which shows "Everything up-to-date")
```

However when i visit origin/b1 i dont see the additional commits.

Can someone suggest what am i missing ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
git fetch upstream               # pull in latest changes from upstream, including b2
git push origin upstream/b2:b1   # push tracking branch upstream/b2 to origin/b1
```

Comment: That did the trick. What was I missing, this worked like magic. can you explain pls.

Comment: I did explain, in the comments.  You basically just want to push `b2` from the remote `upstream` to the branch `b1` from the remote `origin`.  So, you can `git fetch` to get that `b2` branch locally as a tracking branch, and then push it to `b1` on the remote `origin`.

Comment: Thanks. But shouldnt merge of b2 over checkout of b1 should get the latest commits on b1 ?

Comment: Your original efforts were either wrong or at least not what you intended.  You were trying to merge something into a tracking branch (`origin/b1`).  As a general rule, you never mess with your tracking branches, this is the job of Git to do this.